# Automate SQL DB datasource authorisation in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-analysis-services

I have automated the AAS tabular model refresh in ADF V2 using REST API. The Tabular model is deployed with Azure SQL DB as one of the data-source using AAD credentials but the issue is the authorization will be valid for only 2 hours.
In order to automate the authorization as well, I got to know that we can alter the models/databases under AAS Server in Sql Server Management Studio using TMSL scripts(sample script shown at end).

I am trying to generate the refresh token and access token using grant type "password" oauth2 authentication with AAD by giving Web SPN and my azure id credentials. I am providing the tokens under credentials property of alter json TMSL script but it is not working. When I process the database, it is showing the error "The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid. (Source at SQL/Server name;DB name.). The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface."

```
{
    "alter": {
        "object": {
           "database": "Det_clone",
           "dataSource": "SQL/Server name;DB name"
        },
    "dataSource": {
        "type": "structured",
        "name": "SQL/Server name;DB name",
        "connectionDetails": {
            "protocol": "tds",
            "address": {
                 "server": "server address",
                 "database": "DB name"
            }
         },
        "credential": {
            "AuthenticationKind": "OAuth2",
            "kind": "SQL",
            "path": "SQL/Server name;DB name",
            "AccessToken":"***",
            "RefreshToken":"***"
        }
     }
  }
}
```